# Python extracting specific text from tweets

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

Hi I am making an app to extract stock ticker mentions from twitter. I want to know if it's possible to extract a stock ticker from a tweet, for example. My current code:

```
   for account in accounts:
    try:
        statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=account)
        print(account,[s.text for s in statuses])
    except:
        continue
```

Results in this:

```
   DaleJMurray I  this too @DanielKorski
DanZanger $SPX $SPY $ES_F
```

If I apply print ticker as per below it fails to print the tickers, can someone kindly help

```
        ticker = [s.text for s in statuses.split("$")]
        print(ticker)
```

Comment: What is the current output? You say 'the print ticker fails', but we don't know what that means specifically. It could mean that the entire code outputs nothing. It could mean only that line outputs nothing. From my reading, this code should output a whole lot of something, it's helpful to see if that's true or not.

Comment: Sorry the print ticker does not print anything. Not sure why that's happening

Comment: Can you add an example of your output to your question. Otherwise confirm that the entire script outputs nothing.

Comment: This line print(account,[s.text for s in statuses]) works as expected. However, print(ticker), prints nothing at all

Comment: Can you add an example of what print(account,[s.text for s in statuses]) outputs for you. That would let me know what you're working with at that step.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
   statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=account)
        #(account,[s.text for s in statuses])
        x=([s.text for s in statuses][0])
        #print(x)
        y=[word for word in x.split() if word[0] == "$"]
        print(y)
```